# Zend Routing can this be done

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-route

This is possible in Symfony with some routing magic but in Zend I'm not sure how to do this.

I want to make this url

```
http://example.com/unit/view/id/[15]
```

look like this instead

```
http://example.com/unit/[15]/view/[name]
```

where `unit/view` is the controller/action and `id/15` is parameter key=>value, and `[name]` is the name of the unit being retrieved (in this case unit id 15).

Comment: Do you want the name to be looked up automatically (in a database or something like this) or do you add it to your route manually?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it can be done. Using [the router](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html):

In your bootstrap:

```
$router = $zendControllerFront->getRouter();
$router->addRoute('routeName', 
    new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('/unit/:id/view/:name'), 
    array('controller' => 'unit', 'action' => 'view')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the route also in your application.ini:

```
resources.router.routes.myroute.route = ":controller/:id/:action/:name"
```

Then unit maps automatically to your controller (:controller variable here) and the action (:action). More information about these paramters used in Zend_Config files at the manual: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html#zend.controller.router.add-config